# Including common multi-project dependencies within a Podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods

We have a range of iOS/Android games, all built on common, in-house middleware and a standard set of third-party integrations. As much as possible I try to define those integrations in a central place in order to reduce the time spent per game in adding new integrations or removing old ones.

On Android, using Gradle, I'm able to use something of this ilk to fetch standard rules in:

```
apply from: '../../../CTL/android/ctl.gradle'
```

Is there an equivalent in Cocoapods? I've tried the Ruby command `load`, but this seems to create syntax errors. I also looked at creating my own local Podspec, but that seems to expect to have an actual library to fetch and include whereas I'd want basically a null project with dependencies.

Comment: I'm not familiar with gradle, so I'm not sure that's what you want, but a solution could be to use a custom/private podspec that include all the different pods you want. You could also use subspec to separate various kind of pods: DefaultCustom Spec, with SubSpecForLevelDesign (and various pods dependency in it), SubSpecForSocialNetworking (with various subspecs, one for FaceBook, one for Twitter,e etc.), SubspecForHTTPRequest, etc. ?